# PHP: What is the meaning of the syntax using the word 'and'?

Tags: php, syntax

I'm working on making a walker in Wordpress. I saw some example code and it had the following syntax on one of it's lines:

```
!empty($item->attr_title)
and $attributes .= ' title="'.esc_attr($item->attr_title).'"';
```

What does this do? I would assume that if the object attributes are not empty it appends the title string, but I'm not sure the role of the "and" word here.

Comment: Read [Logical Operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php) and [Operator Precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php).

Comment: it uses logical short circuting to do conditionally do an assignment.

Comment: Yikes, I don't recommend you write code like that. It's a clever trick, as Dave points out, but it's not very clear.

Comment: It does what you assume. It's an expression and the right-of-the-and part is only executed in case the left-of-the-and part evaluated true already - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation

Answer (score 5):

That's a shorthand for:

```
if (!empty($item->attr_title)) {
   $attributes .= ' title="'.esc_attr($item->attr_title).'"';
}
```

Answer (score 5):

PHP does short circuit evaluation of boolean expressions, that is, only as many terms are evaluated until the result is definite.

```
true and something()
```

will evaluate `something()` (the complete expression could still eval to false), whereas

```
false and something()
```

will stop evaluating after the `false` term.

Answer (score 2):

This is an example of "[short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation)".

This is basically a short hand way of writing:

```
if(!empty($item->attr_title)) {
    $attributes .= ...
}
```

It works because the boolean operation `and` stops evaluation if the first term is falsy. If it's truthy, the right hand side is evaluated. Since we're not interested in the return value, this has the same effect as the if statement.

Answer (score 1):

The `and` keyword (in this case the same as `&&`) checks if the condition left of it **and** the one right of it are true. There is an optimation that if the left hand condition is false the right hand one will not be checked or executed. So your code would be the same as:

```
if(!empty($item->attr_title) {
    $attributes .= ' title="'.esc_attr($item->attr_title).'"';
}
```

Comment: + for mentioning the relation to `&&`.

Comment: Except it's not the same — they have difference precedences.

Comment: but because of the associativity this should not make much of a difference here.